# Python: Why doesn't this throw an exception?

Tags: python, python-2.7, error-handling, try-catch

The following code returns:

`TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects`

Why doesn't it throw the exception?

```
while True:
    try:
        print "test" + 1
    except ValueError:
        print "You can't concatenate that different object types silly"
```

Comment: `ValueError` and `TypeError` are not the same word

Comment: It's good for you that it didn't run, that's an infinite loop if you replace ValueError with TypeError!

Comment: change `catch ValueError:` to `catch TypeError:`. And remove the `while True`, obviously, unless you want to see your error message repeated ad infinitum.

Comment: Thanks! I am new and didn't realise theose exception types meant something.

Comment: @Kevin Um, Python uses `except`, not `catch`. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can catch the Exception like this:

```
try:
    print "test" + 1
except ValueError:
    print "You can't concatenate that different object types silly"
except TypeError:
    print "TypeError and the words you want to say"
```